# Detect DST from a date entered by user in bash

Tags: bash, shell, dst

I am trying to write a bash script that takes in a users input of a specific date in a format such as MM/DD/YYYY and returns whether or not that specific date was during daylight savings time or not.  Is there a specific function that checks this? Does the date command have a way to do this?  I am using RHEL 6.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get GNU date to tell you the time zone abreviation. This will change if DST is in effect:

```
TZ=US/Pacific date --date '2015/05/12' +%Z
```

Returns:

```
PDT
```

And:

```
TZ=US/Pacific date --date '2015/12/12' +%Z
```

Returns:

```
PST
```

I don't see a way to get whether DST is in effect explicitely from `date`, but depending on what you are trying to accomplish this may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!  I totally forgot that the timezone changed when it was in daylight savings time.  Thanks.

Comment: The *time zone* does not change. It is still `US/Pacific`.  The time zone *offset* changes, as does the associated time zone *abbreviation*.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the perl [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) module for this:

```
perl -MDateTime -E '
    ($y, $m, $d) = split(/-/, shift);
    $dt = DateTime->new(year=>$y, month=>$m, day=>$d, time_zone=>"local");
    say $dt->is_dst;
' "2015-06-15"
```

```
1
```

```
perl -MDateTime -E '
    ($y, $m, $d) = split(/-/, shift);
    $dt = DateTime->new(year=>$y, month=>$m, day=>$d, time_zone=>"local");
    say $dt->is_dst;
' "2015-01-15"
```

```
0
```

Comment: Be aware that many timezones do not use DST, Asia/Tokyo and Canada/Saskatchewan being two.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will take a look at perl for this problem